# How to allow https to access files from server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers, ssl-certificate

I was using http and recently installed ssl certificate and now images are no longer loading.

But i figured it out that it's the following line in my .htaccess.

What does this line do and how do i modify it to to allow https?

```
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

- Do i really need this line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule says return `FORBIDDEN` HTTP 403 to the image file requests. You may safely comment out/remove the directive.

Comment: Ok but won't this allow directory listing or access of any sort that may cause bad results?

Comment: It will not because this particular directive is returning HTTP 403 only for image files, nothing else.